# Timer from another form not stopping

Tags: c#, winforms

*Architecture*

```
___ParentForm
   |___Timer
   |___Panel___ChildForm
               |___StopButton
```

I've got a `ParentForm` with an attached `Timer` and a `Panel` containing the `ChildForm`.

*Problem encountered*

I want to stop the `ParentForm`'s timer from the `ChildForm` but the timer is never stopping.

*What I've tried*

```
// timer modifiers = Public

private void stopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ParentForm parentForm = new ParentForm();
        parentForm.timer.Stop();
        parentForm.timer.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: You're creating a new parent form instead of getting the existing one.

Comment: You could write something like: `(this.ParentForm as [The Parent Form class]).[The Timer Instance].Stop()`. Of course the Timer needs to be public and the `StopButton` class needs to know the Type of its Parent. Not really good. Your `StopButton` could raise a public event when that button is clicked, let the Form that creates `StopButton` subscribe to this event and stop the timer in its handler.

Comment: Or use an Interface. Make the `ParentForm` class implement a known/common Interface that defines a `StopTimer()` method. In `StopButton` you check whether `this.ParentForm` implements the Interface and, if so, cast it and call that method. -- You should probably use UserControls instead of Forms (just IMO).

Comment: Thank you guys so much for the help. It totally works, @Jimi! I'm going now for implementing the `Interface` and `UserControls`. Great advice, you're too kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an event in the child form and subscribe to the event in the parent form. Clicking the button in the child form raises the event. In the event handler on the parent form, stop the timer.

**ParentForm.cs**

```
public partial class ParentForm : Form
{
    ChildForm childForm = null;

    public ParentForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ParentForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        toolStripStatusLabel2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
        statusStrip1.Refresh();
    }

    private void btnOpenChildForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (childForm == null || childForm.IsDisposed)
        {
            childForm = new ChildForm();

            //subscribe to events
            childForm.FormClosed += ChildForm_FormClosed;
            childForm.StopTimerButtonClicked += ChildForm_StopTimerButtonClicked;
            
            childForm.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            childForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            childForm.Activate();
        }
        
    }

    private void ChildForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        //unsubscribe from events
        childForm.FormClosed -= ChildForm_FormClosed;
        childForm.StopTimerButtonClicked -= ChildForm_StopTimerButtonClicked;

        childForm = null;
    }

    private void ChildForm_StopTimerButtonClicked(object sender, bool e)
    {
        //stop timer
        timer1.Stop();
    }
}
```

**ChildForm.cs**

```
public partial class ChildForm : Form
{
    public delegate void EventHandlerStopTimerButtonClicked(object sender, bool e);


    //event that subscribers can subscribe to
    public event EventHandlerStopTimerButtonClicked StopTimerButtonClicked;

    public ChildForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (StopTimerButtonClicked != null)
        {
            //raise event
            StopTimerButtonClicked(this, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was just learning how to to it properly. Yours is perfect, @user9938! Thank you for teaching me, I hope it will help others in the future. I wish you the best.